# Qt designer, opening a pop up window when pushing a button

Tags: qt-designer

I've looked for hours on the web for information on this and i'm yet to find something that works for me, there's not much information on this for Qt Designer.

I have a mainwindow, when you push a button on the main window a pop up window is supposed to be opened, i've tried with signal/slots but as you see in the picture below i am not able to do it. What am i missing?

[image]

Comment: Qt Designer is not an IDE.

Comment: I know its not an IDE, but i plan on doing something with that button there, when it opens the dialog, the dialog will require the user to input something, i'm using PyQt for that..

Comment: See [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) in the PyQt docs for how to import the ui into your application.